# URL redirection breaks Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor

I have updated a redirection rule for my site,

```
<rule name="main mysitecom redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:(www|local))?(.mysite\.com)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/en" appendQueryString="false" />
```

This rule will redirect the page to default language "en" when user types the url on browser. Sitecore login -> Experience editor through this url is not working. When I try to open any item in experience editor while accessing through the given url in browser, it is redirecting to home page directly.

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Try adding `<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^$" />` to `<conditions>` to make sure your rule is only executed when there is no query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by updating the following line to 
`<conditions>` in Rewrite rules

```
<add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="\?.*sc_mode" negate="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add condition

```
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^$" />
```

to `<conditions>` of your rule:

```
<rule name="main mysitecom redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:(www|local))?(.mysite\.com)$" />
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/en" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

This will make sure your redirect is only executed when url doesn't have query string which is the case for Experience Editor which uses `sc_mode` parameter.

You **should not** exclude `sc_mode` parameter only, as there may be other meaningful query strings which you don't want redirect (e.g. `sc_camp` for campaign id which will never be triggered if you check `sc_mode` parameter only).